# error when import snack project from github

Tags: react-native, github, expo

when i try to use Import git repository in snack to edit my react native project this error is displayed : An error occurred during import. This could be because the data provided was invalid, or because the repository referenced is not a properly formatted Expo project.

my github link is : https://github.com/saeedjafary/SarvShop

I am seeing this error recently. there was no problem before

Answer (score 1):

A late answer; but, to anyone faced this issue, click on **Show Advanced Options** in **Branch name** Specify the branch if it isn't the master, **GitHub** now uses **main** as the main branch.